# XML Tag grouping in RTF Template to suppress duplicates

Tags: xml, oracle, rtf, bi-publisher, oracle-xml-publisher

My XML Tag generated is as follows-

```
<P_MONTH>01</P_MONTH>


-<G_1>

<DIVISION>CA Division</DIVISION>

<DISTRICT>CA District</DISTRICT>

<DEPARTMENT>Global Operations</DEPARTMENT>

<DEP_EMPL_COUNT>9</DEP_EMPL_COUNT>

</G_1>


-<G_1>

<DIVISION>CA Division</DIVISION>

<DISTRICT>CA District</DISTRICT>

<DEPARTMENT>Laboratory Services</DEPARTMENT>

<DEP_EMPL_COUNT>11</DEP_EMPL_COUNT>

</G_1>


-<G_1>

<DIVISION>CA Division</DIVISION>

<DISTRICT>CA District</DISTRICT>

<DEPARTMENT>Corporate</DEPARTMENT>

<DEP_EMPL_COUNT>3</DEP_EMPL_COUNT>

</G_1>


-<G_1>

<DIVISION>CA Division</DIVISION>

<DISTRICT>S District</DISTRICT>

<DEPARTMENT>Corporate Administration</DEPARTMENT>

<DEP_EMPL_COUNT>6</DEP_EMPL_COUNT>

</G_1>


-<G_1>

<DIVISION>CA Division</DIVISION>

<DISTRICT>S District</DISTRICT>

<DEPARTMENT>Corporate Technology</DEPARTMENT>

<DEP_EMPL_COUNT>1</DEP_EMPL_COUNT>

</G_1>
```

When I am using these tag like below in the RTF template-

```
DIVISION                            DISTRICT                    DEPARTMENT                 COUNT
<?for-each:G_1?> <DIVISION>         <DISTRICT>                   <DEPARTMENT>             <COUNT> <?end for-each?>
```

This is giving an output like -

```
DIVISION              DISTRICT                          DEPARTMENT                      COUNT
CA Division           CA District                     Global Operations                  9
CA Division           CA District                     Laboratory Services                11
CA Division           CA District                     Corporate                          3
CA Division           S District                      Corporate Administration           6 
CA Division           S District                      Corporate Technology               1
```

I want the repeated values in division and district to be suppressed and the output to look like -

```
DIVISION              DISTRICT                          DEPARTMENT                      COUNT
CA Division           CA District                     Global Operations                  9
                                                      Laboratory Services                11
                                                      Corporate                          3
                      S District                      Corporate Administration           6 
                                                      Corporate Technology               1
```

How can this be achieved ? I am not being able to use for-each-group properly to group the tags. Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use variables. Something like this:

**RTF**
[image]
Make sure you put your "if" logic in the alt-text/field properties, else, it may not work. I took it out so you could see it better here.

**Output**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd use nested tables and for-each-group functionality.

**RTF:**
[image]

**Output**
[image]

Comment: the only issue I am facing with this solution is that I have to show the borders of the table. with the nested table it is difficult to place it exactly of the same size

Comment: Ya, it can be difficult at times. You you have few options to help. 1) don't show borders. You see in my example I hid many of the borders. 2) change the margins to 0 for the parent cell with nested tables. [place cursers in the bottom of the cell, right click, table properties, cell tab, right/left margins = 0.] 3) drag the cell dividers on the ruler on parent and child tables so they snap to the same spot.

Comment: i want the output to be excel hence I think it is getting a little difficult to get the "Look" correct... the same solution you provided above will work in excel template too ?

Comment: @EdHayes3- I have asked another question with the exact format issue.. can you pls check if you have any suggestions

Comment: BI Bublisher Excel output is not the best. Especially for large data sets, from an RTF template. I would not suggest showing one attribute once per group of data rather than repeating it for each row. Instead, use an Excel pivot table to do that for "reporting". If you remove the value from all Excel rows except the first row, it's essentially like having database records with a null value. It will impede peoples ability to use the data.